# Handling ORA-01403: no data found with exception in trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, oracle11g, triggers

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Patient
(
    p_Name  VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    p_Surname VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    idP     INTEGER,
    b_Date  DATE NOT NULL,
    d_Date  DATE DEFAULT NULL,
 
    CONSTRAINT PK_idP PRIMARY KEY(idP)
);

CREATE TABLE Visit 
(
    idV   INTEGER,
    date_V  DATE NOT NULL,
    v_Hospital INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_PV   INTEGER,

    CONSTRAINT PK_idV PRIMARY KEY(idV),
    CONSTRAINT FK_idPV FOREIGN KEY(id_PV) REFERENCES Patient(idp)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_idHV FOREIGN KEY(v_Hospital) REFERENCES Hospital(idH)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I've created a trigger so that when I insert a row into the table Visit it shouldn't allow me to do that if the patient is deceased (of course), that's the logic behind it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER visitDeceased
BEFORE INSERT ON Visit
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    pd Patient.d_date%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT P.d_date INTO pd
    FROM Patient P JOIN Visit V ON P.idP=:NEW.id_PV;
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  
        INSERT INTO Visit(date_V,v_Hospital,id_PV) VALUES(:NEW.date_V,:NEW.v_Hospital,:NEW.id_PV);
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20111,'Error. Patient deceased.'); 
END;
/
```

The problem is that the when the d_date is NULL the code makes a ORA-01403: no data found error. I'm trying to handle that with that exception but doesn't work. Someone knows how to make it work? Thanks a lot.

Comment: WHat is your criteria to identify the deceased patient?

Comment: I update the Patient table inserting a date into the d_date attribute (d stands for decease).

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting one row to match and can work with a `NULL` value for a non-match, then I find that aggregation is convenient:

```
SELECT MAX(P.d_date) INTO pd
FROM Patient P JOIN
     Visit V
     ON P.idP = :NEW.id_PV;
```

However, in your code, I would just use `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO Visit (date_V, v_Hospital, id_PV) V. 
    SELECT :NEW.date_V, :NEW.v_Hospital, :NEW.id_PV
    FROM dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM Patient p
                      WHERE p.idP = :NEW.id_PV
                     );
```

For legal reasons, you may have to remove deceased patients from `Patient`.  However, if that is not a requirement, I would suggest using a flag or `deceased_date` instead.

Also, this problem could be avoided by having a foreign key constraint.  That would validate the relational integrity without having to rely on a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly.

`NO_DATA_FOUND` handles the exception when `SELECT P.d_date INTO pd FROM Patient P JOIN Visit V ON P.idP=:NEW.id_PV;` returns no row. It doesn't handle when row exists for this query, however, `d_date` is null. And that is possible according to your table structure `d_Date  DATE DEFAULT NULL`. You can handle this by:

*make a check on `pd` if it is null after your `select` query.
e.g :

```
IF pd IS NULL THEN    
-- do your work 
END IF;
```

`OR`

*add a check `where P.d_date is not null` in below query.

`SELECT P.d_date INTO pd FROM Patient P JOIN Visit V ON P.idP=:NEW.id_PV where P.d_date is not null;`

Answer (score 0):

When you are running your trigger on insert statement on VISIT table the why you are using Insert statement inside it? Just remove your Insert statement and it should work then -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER visitDeceased
BEFORE INSERT ON Visit
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    pd Patient.d_date%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT P.d_date INTO pd
    FROM Patient P JOIN Visit V ON P.idP=:NEW.id_PV;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20111,'Error. Patient deceased.'); 
END;
/
```

[Link.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fb307f8bbfbd9bd8f49a0cb993349c23)

Comment: It shows the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR regardless of the patient being alive or not if I do that.